# DLL load failed when importing rasterio

Tags: python, dll, spyder, rasterio

I have a conda environment, from where I installed the packages rioxarray and matplotlib for reading in a netCDF file. In rioxarray is also the package rasterio included, which gives me the following error message:

"from rasterio._base import gdal_version"
"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing_base: The specified module could not be found."

I'm using Python version 3.10, rasterio 1.2.10 and spyder 5.4.2.

I would appreciate any help to solve my issue. Please let me know, if you need more information about my problem.